# python-pandas: use values as index and count them in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Need help with pandas.

I have this dataframe:

```
a    b    c
Yes  No   Yes
Yes  Yes  No
Yes  No   No
```

How can I implement a Pandas code that will turn my dataframe to:

```
     a    b     c
Yes  3    1     1
No   0    2     2
```

I'm looking into using iloc and lambda but i'm really clueless. Is there a way for me to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

This actually does the trick:

```
df.apply(pd.value_counts)
```